# Circular dependency when trying to install openssl and openssl-libs on CentOS

Tags: centos, openssl

I want to install my c++ library on my CentOS 7.2 server. When I'm trying to compile it with g++ The compiler says this error `invalid use of incomplete type ‘HMAC_CTX {aka struct hmac_ctx_st}`.
I googled the error and itis reletad to an old version of OpenSSL.

When I'm trying to install the newest OpenSSL version (1.1.0c) the rmp requires to install `libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)`.

I tried to install the newest version with `yum install openssl-libs-1.1.0c-2.fc26.x86_64.rpm`. When I'm installing `openssl-libs` he rpm requires to install `libssl.so.10()(64bit)`.

How can I resolve the circular dependency between them?

Comment: You're trying to install a Fedora RPM (**`... .fc26. ...`**) on CentOS which is unlikely to work.

Comment: I'm new to CentOS. I'm understanding that fedora 26 is not the right package manager for me. Is there an official  packages index for CentOS 7 (fedora 19)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're compiling programs against the system libraries, you need to install the appropriate `-devel` packages so that the headers are available. For instance `openssl-devel`.

There is no need to attempt to locate (wrong) packages from different Linux distributions, and that won't even work anyway.